# Python - Mechanize - import failure (python 3.3 on MacOS 10.7)

Tags: macos, python-3.x, mechanize, mechanize-python

Installed mechanize successfully on MacOS 10.7 with Python3.3.

But when I try it I get failure.

```
>>> import mechanize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py3.3.egg/mechanize/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
ImportError: No module named '_version'
>>>
```

Here's the environment:

```
>>> print (sys.version)
3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 01:12:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

>>> print(*sys.path, sep='\n')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-3.1-py3.3.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py3.3.egg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python33.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
>>>
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Windows 7. They say here http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/documentation.html#compatibility that 
"mechanize works with Python 2.4, Python 2.5, Python 2.6, and Python 2.7." It seems that 3.3 version is not supported.